# Мало()отличимо -- слитно или раздельно?

Tags: морфология, слитно-раздельно

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "*мало отличимо* от других сообщений" или "*малоотличимо* от других сообщений"?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

В данном конкретном случае пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

Раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

раздельно